# How can I loop a list of items within a looped component in Angluar so that the icons and text doesn't appear if they're not in JSON file?

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, components

I've made looped a card where I am trying to show my projects and a bit of meta-data about them. Most of the meta-data are one time data so I don't need to loop them.

But the roles section ([Highlighted in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHVcT.png)) has multiple roles in them. Some cards will have 2 roles and some 4 roles. I don't know how to loop them inside an already existing looped component.

Here's how I my code works ATM:

[landing / projects-section / landing-projects.component.html](https://github.com/sankalpdomore/sankalpsinha.com-v4/blob/develop/src/app/components/landing/projects-section/landing-projects.component.html)

```
<div class="container-fluid common-page-container landing-projects-container">
    <div #target class="container-fluid content-container">
        <h1 class="common-page-header-h1 with-subheader">
            Fortune favours the bold <span>(font)</span>
        </h1>
        <div class="common-page-sub-header">
            Over my 8+ years of designing, I have been lucky enough to work with some amazing people & teams. Together, we’ve <br>
            discussed and figured user problems, debated the best UX to solve them, and delivered decent products to test the water.<br>
            Below is a selected list of projects that I’ve helped companies design & build over the years.<br>
            Some are a success, some are a failure - but all learning in disguise ✨
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let item of data" class="landing-projects-section-container col-12">
                <component-projects-card ProjectTitle={{item.ProjectTitle}} ProjectDescription={{item.ProjectDescription}} ProjectImage={{item.ProjectImage}} ProjectDate={{item.ProjectDate}} ProjectWorkTitle={{item.ProjectWorkTitle}} ProjectRoles1={{item.ProjectRoles1}} ProjectRoles2={{item.ProjectRoles2}} ProjectRoles3={{item.ProjectRoles3}} ProjectRoles4={{item.ProjectRoles4}}>
                </component-projects-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[landing / projects-section / landing-projects.component.ts](https://github.com/sankalpdomore/sankalpsinha.com-v4/blob/develop/src/app/components/landing/projects-section/landing-projects.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-landing-projects',
  templateUrl: './landing-projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-projects.component.css']
})
export class LandingProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any =

    [
      {
        "ProjectTitle": "SellerCrowd",
        "ProjectDescription": "Designing a social platform to help salespeople exchange insights anonymously & hit sales goals faster.",
        "ProjectImage": "../assets/projects/project-tiles/sellercrowd.png",
        "ProjectDate": "Jan ’18 - Oct ‘21",
        "ProjectWorkTitle": "Senior Product Designer",
        "ProjectRoles1": "I was hired by SellerCrowd during a time when the code + design wasn’t scalable. The company was looking to redesign the product from scratch.",
        "ProjectRoles2": "Understood user problems by looking at user feedback, talking to users, & analyzing user behavior with tools like Smartlook.",
        "ProjectRoles3": "Working cross-functionally to define product strategy & roadmaps in collaboration with the Product & Engg. team - while keeping in mind the user and business goals and trying to strike a balance between the two.",
        "ProjectRoles4": "Designing + prototyping solutions and ensuring pixel-perfect implementation of the interface & experience in collaboration with the QA & Engg. team.",
        "ProjectRandomFact": "SellerCrowd was my first remote job and my  first day with the company was at a company-wide yearly meetup in Madrid, Spain ",
        "ProjectTeamSize": "2 PMs, 9 Devs, 3 QAs, 1 Designer (me)",
        "ProjectURL": "www.sellercrowd.com",
      },
    ]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

[landing / projects-card / projects-card.component.html](https://github.com/sankalpdomore/sankalpsinha.com-v4/blob/develop/src/app/components/landing/projects-card/projects-card.component.html)

```
<div class="row projects-card-container">
    <div class="col-5 projects-card-container-left">
        <div class="projects-card-container-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\''+ ProjectImage + '\')'}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 projects-card-container-right">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="projects-card-container-right-title-description">
                <span class="projects-card-title">{{ProjectTitle}}</span>
                <span class="projects-card-title-right-line">------</span>
                <span class="projects-card-description">{{ProjectDescription}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-time.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectDate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-title.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectWorkTitle}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-roles.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-role">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectRoles1}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-roles.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-role">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectRoles2}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-roles.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-role">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectRoles3}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-roles.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-role">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectRoles4}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[landing / projects-card / projects-card.component.ts](https://github.com/sankalpdomore/sankalpsinha.com-v4/blob/develop/src/app/components/landing/projects-card/projects-card.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-projects-card',
  templateUrl: './projects-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-card.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  ProjectTitle: String

  @Input()
  ProjectDescription: String

  @Input()
  ProjectImage: String

  @Input()
  ProjectDate: String

  @Input()
  ProjectWorkTitle: String

  @Input()
  ProjectRoles1: String

  @Input()
  ProjectRoles2: String

  @Input()
  ProjectRoles3: String

  @Input()
  ProjectRoles4: String

  @Input()
  ProjectRandomFact: String

  @Input()
  ProjectTeamSize: String

  @Input()
  ProjectURL: String

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Comment: any updates on my answer ?

Comment: Hey @ShashankVivek, yes. I tried the way you suggested but I may be doing something wrong in writing the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not create an array of roles ?

```
export class LandingProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any =

    [
      {
        "ProjectTitle": "SellerCrowd",
        "ProjectDescription": "Designing a social platform to help salespeople exchange insights anonymously & hit sales goals faster.",
        "ProjectImage": "../assets/projects/project-tiles/sellercrowd.png",
        "ProjectDate": "Jan ’18 - Oct ‘21",
        "ProjectWorkTitle": "Senior Product Designer",
        "roles": [
         "I was hired by SellerCrowd during a time when the code + design wasn’t scalable. The company was looking to redesign the product from scratch.",
        "Understood user problems by looking at user feedback, talking to users, & analyzing user behavior with tools like Smartlook.",
        "Working cross-functionally to define product strategy & roadmaps in collaboration with the Product & Engg. team - while keeping in mind the user and business goals and trying to strike a balance between the two.",
        "Designing + prototyping solutions and ensuring pixel-perfect implementation of the interface & experience in collaboration with the QA & Engg. team."
        ]
        "ProjectRandomFact": "SellerCrowd was my first remote job and my  first day with the company was at a company-wide yearly meetup in Madrid, Spain ",
        "ProjectTeamSize": "2 PMs, 9 Devs, 3 QAs, 1 Designer (me)",
        "ProjectURL": "www.sellercrowd.com",
      },
    ]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

and then loop over them as

```
<div class="row projects-card-container">
    <div class="col-5 projects-card-container-left">
        <div class="projects-card-container-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(\''+ ProjectImage + '\')'}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 projects-card-container-right">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="projects-card-container-right-title-description">
                <span class="projects-card-title">{{ProjectTitle}}</span>
                <span class="projects-card-title-right-line">------</span>
                <span class="projects-card-description">{{ProjectDescription}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-time.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectDate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-title.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectWorkTitle}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngFor="let role of roles" class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-roles.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-role">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{role}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex projects-card-container-right-meta-data">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="../assets/projects/icon-roles.svg" alt="" class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-icons icon-project-role">
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects-card-container-right-meta-data-text">
                        {{ProjectRoles4}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Also, do not make so many `@Input()` params in `ProjectsCardComponent`. Make a single param lets say `@INput() data` and create an obj with all the properties that you are passing separately.
   **Reason**:

- You can create `type` for that object using typescript and control what is required.
- You will have lesser code on HTML and you can move the responsibility to create proper payload into your component. Better quality !
- There are other reasons as well but then we need to dive into how we should design components and so on. It'll deviate away from this question.

Comment: Hey Shashank, here's where I am stuck.

I created the the array of roles and looped them but it's not rendering.

Here's the screenshot of the render: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oAqo.png It's not looping the array of roles at all.

Is there something that I need to change on `ProjectsCardComponent`?

Comment: @SankalpSinha it would be impossible to give you the exact solution without looking at your code. I checked  https://github.com/sankalpdomore/sankalpsinha.com-v4/blob/develop/src/app/components/landing/projects-card/projects-card.component.html and it is not reflecting your problem. Now, what you can do to debug this is to write `{{roles | json}}` in `html`  and verify that it is actually an array of strings.  DO let me know if you are also seeing any error in `developer console` of browser

Comment: let me try those, will report back. Thanks again!

Comment: @SankalpSinha: I hope it had worked